# Is there a way to use a Tailwind custom class in @apply?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I've defined a custom Tailwind class, but can't seem to use it in my CSS `@apply`.

In Tailwind CSS you can add a custom class in `tailwind.config.js` like this:

```js
extend: {
  boxShadow:{
    "specific":'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 3px 6px'
  }
}
```

I can add this class to an element and see the shadow, but when I try to use it in `@apply` I get this error:

> The `shadow-specific` class does not exist. If `shadow-specific` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.

Here is how I'm using the class with `@apply`:

```css
.product .title {
   @apply py-2 font-extrabold text-lg md:text-base shadow-specific;
}
```

I also tried defining the class in `index.css` with the `@layer` directive:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .shadow-specific {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 3px 6px;
  }
}
```

Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this using Astro. Turns out this behavior is expected.

> If you try to @apply a custom class you’ve defined in your global CSS in one of these per-component  blocks, you’ll get an error about the class not existing.

> The solution to this problem is to define any custom styles you want to @apply in your components using the plugin system instead.

```
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addComponents, theme }) {
      addComponents({
        '.shadow-specific': {
          boxShadow: theme('boxShadow.xl'),
        }
      })
    })
  ]
}
```

Reference: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#using-apply-with-per-component-css

Answer (score -1):

class should not inside @apply.

The correct way:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@layer components{
  .shadow-specific{
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 3px 6px;
  }
}
```

then on your component for example:

```
<div className="shadow-specific">
```

Comment: i know how it's work .I want to do it as I explained